# Can't install practically macro on eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, macros

I can't install practically macro on eclipse.`

Error:

> Communication with repository at
>   http://puremvcnotificationviewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PracticallyMacroGoogleUpdateSite
>   failed.
>   Read Timeout

Tried to install from here https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/practically-macro-0 dragging and dropping
And tried to install it from eclipse marketplace, both said the same thing.

I have eclipse luna 4.4.1.

I want to be able to do key shortcut for run cofiguration. Apperently i need this plug-in but can't install it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/?source=typ_redirect and download PracticallyMacro_x.x.x.jar.

Then create a directory "PracticallyMarco" inside the eclipse/plugins directory.

Extract all files from PracticallyMacro_x.x.x.jar into eclipse/plugins/PracticallyMarco.

Restart eclipse. (Maybe you should restart eclipse with the -clean option.) 
Then you can use the PracticallyMacro from the main toolbar:

[image: Practically Macro can be accessed from the main toolbar]

See also the file eclipse/plugins/PracticallyMarco/Instructions.txt for more details.

Comment: Worked for me... I had to use -clean: "Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory and insert -clean as the first line."

Answer (score 2):

There is a GitHub fork that seems to work:

https://github.com/EmteZogaf/practicalmacro-site/

If you browse the repo you can find the following update site:

https://github.com/EmteZogaf/practicalmacro-site/raw/master

I tested it on latest eclipse PHOTON and it seems to work.